# Search by an attribute of a referenced table using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

ok i got this schemas of user

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});
```

and this of a marker, as you can see Marker knows it's User

```
const MarkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lat: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Double
  },
  lng: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Double
  },
  user: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
});
```

i need to know the `Markers` of a `User` by `name` of `User` with one query
and i can't filter in the populate because it's not a join.

so anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two queries. One for the user (actually the users id) and then another for the Marker.  No way around it.

You should be able to keep that id handy someplace though, like on the session?

Comment: yeah seems like it, either that or change the model. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
//With One query, you need to go through all the records in Marks Schema.  

//get the name from the request body
const search_name = req.body.name;


MarkSchema.find({}).populate("user").exec((err,marks)=>{
     if(err){ 
        //handle
     }
     else{
        const filteredMark = marks.filter((mark)=>{
           return mark.user.name === search_name
        })

        //console.log(filteredMark[0])

     }
});
```

Comment: ok that's a big no no here there are tons of this markers, but thanks anyway. for making me realize

Comment: Another workaround would be to make your UserSchema reference MarksSchema.